# A manhwa where the main character is already a powerful cultivator and has 5 or so female companions from the start

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character (male) is already some kind of a master in his world. He has 5 female companions who are close with him, but he does not like their company that much, and tries to ascend to a new world to escape them. However they also ascend with him to the new world.

They get separated and the main character slowly finds all of his companions and restores his power in the new world (which goes from cultivation to classic fantasy elf and stuff)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Possible *[My Harem Grew So Large, I Was Forced To Ascend](https://comick.app/comic/my-harem-grew-so-large-i-was-forced-to-ascend)* by 黎之恒.

[image: One of the manhua covers]

> Tsundere heavenly master, big-breasted sister, barefoot poison cultivator, immortal swordswoman with white silk clothes, the last 5 out of the 6 strongest people in the world. I, Ye Gulou have become the first person to cultivate immortality through pure unbounded Yang. But wait, cultivating pure unbounded Yang means I can't form relationships with women or else I'll die?! Then what can I do about this harem of mine that's grown so large over the years? They're all chasing me down, coercing me to choose between them (otherwise they'll kill Me). They've forced me to ascend to the Heavens, to immortality right now to escape from their wrath. Oh shit, they followed me to the new world?!! Let's see what awaits us as my harems from both worlds combine!

Found with a search for `manhua cultivator harem ascends "fantasy world"`